# Recursion: If Divider Doesn't Divide The Number --> Divider goes up by one untill divider === number

Tags: javascript

```
The number equals 100 ("this is not the code. I am illustrating the problem")
script : (
   number: divider,
   100/2 = 50 --> It can be divided by 2 again and still more than 0,
   50/2 = 25 --> It can be divided by 2 again and still more than 0,
   -->25/2 = It cannot be divided by 2 anymore(12.5)but it's still more than 0, so the divider goes up by one,

   25/3 = but it's still more than 0, so the divider goes up by one,
   25/4 = but it's still more than 0, so the divider goes up by one,
   25/5 = 25/5 can be divided,
   5 "===" 5 condition met
)
```

I currently stuck on --> step please help any other suggestion is greatly appreciated.
Reason: just trying to automate a math problem for my homework
Math problem: count how many times can the number be divided by 2, 3, 5...

```
var number = 100;


function howMuch(n, divider = 2){
  if( Math.floor(n) !== n){
    console.log(n)
    if(n > 0){ //maybe here the condition is not right?
      return howMuch( divider++)
    } else return;
  } else {
            console.log(n)

    return howMuch(n / divider)
  }
}

console.log(howMuch(number))
```

Comment: when this process is finished, what is the intended return value?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's frowned upon to modify the code in a question in a way that changes the behavior since comments and answers may no longer apply.  Since only one answer (which isn't based on your code) is currently here, and no comments currently exist that address the earlier version, it's probably okay to leave the change...but something to know for the future.

Comment: @beska that fixed that but somehow 12.5 passed the if(Math.floor(n) === n) test. so the divider goes up  and I am stuck in infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple problems with the logic you had. Some are

1. divider was always 2
2. to see if something perfectly divides, like if `n` is perfectly divisible by `a`, `n%a` would be 0
3. *There might be more but im not sure how to word it ;-;*

```js
//recursion example
function howMuch(n,divider){
  divider=divider||2 //so that you can pass in divider values and default to 2 at the start
  while(n%divider){divider++} //adds until divider can divide without remainder
  console.log(`${n}/${divider}=${n/divider}`) //the log of the division statement
  n/=divider //the division statement
  if(n===divider){return "Success"} //when mission complete
  return howMuch(n,divider) //else recurse
}

//example
//btw im not sure if u want it in 1 string or separate stings, but ur question code seemed like separate strings so that's what i did
console.log(howMuch(100))
```

Comment: If you have a question, it is more appropriate to post that as a comment to the OP.

Comment: i posted it so i can edit the answer based on the response but ok ;-;

Comment: Is while(n%divider) same as Math.floor(n) === n?

Comment: @trincot i took away the question in my answer.. pls remove the minus :{

Comment: You used recursion which I wanted  but I wanted to log 100 / 2; 50/2; 25/5

Comment: @NewGuy9000 `n` is the thing being divided cleanly.. so, it should always be a whole number.. `n%divider` tests to see if it divides cleanly and yes i'll be right on that gimme 5 minutes cuz i type slow ;-;

Comment: @NewGuy9000 check now :D

Comment: wow, you are a pro at this. I was trying to log it out but you wrote it faaasteer and way better

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion for this.

```
function howMuch(n) {
  let divisor = 2;
  while (true) {
    let result = n / divisor;
    if (result < 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (result != Math.floor(result)) {
      divisor++;
      continue;
    }
    console.log(n, "/", divisor, "=", result);
    n = result;
  }
}

howMuch(100);
```

prints out

```
100 / 2 = 50
50 / 2 = 25
25 / 5 = 5
5 / 5 = 1
```

Comment: True.  But this doesn't answer the question of what is wrong with his code.  I guess it's up to the asker to decide if (s)he just wants working code, or wants to know what's wrong.

Comment: The thing is I wanted to torture myself by using recursion  but thanks